# Can you extract part of HTML to template and call it from more than one place

Tags: html, angular

I have duplicate code in my HTML. When I have it in Java i mark the code in IntelliJ and select "extract method" => "replace 2 occurrences".
I want to do the same for HTML and have the following solution, but I think its ugly:

```
<ng-template #banner1>
  stuff...
</ng-template>

<ng-template #banner2>
  other stuff...
</ng-template>

<div class="row tight">    
  <div class="col-sm-6 hidden-print">
    <ng-container *ngIf="false; else banner1"></ng-container>
  </div> 

  <div class="col-sm-6 hidden-print">
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <ng-container *ngIf="false; else banner2"></ng-container>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      stuff3...
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-8 visible-print">
    <ng-container *ngIf="false; else banner1"></ng-container>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 visible-print">
    <ng-container *ngIf="false; else banner2"></ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code above WORKS (if I have copy/paste it correctly) but it needs improvement...

The whole reason for the duplicated code is that I want different styling for the code when printing on paper and then viewing on screen.

I don't like this part:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="false; else banner1"></ng-container>
```

I want something like

```
<ng-inject template="banner1"></ng-inject>
```

or something even better.

Comment: Create component and use it multi times with conditional logic.

Comment: Yes, thanks, but that generates 4 extra files and unnecessary separation of logic. The code in "stuff" and "other stuff" are pretty small, so it is a bit of overkill...

Comment: how many line of code in `stuff` and `other-stuff` have?

Comment: Approx 15 lines each

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's `ngTemplateOutlet` directive that can help you with this. The syntax is very simple - `<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="yourTemplate"></ng-container>`

Example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xh9ebz

Comment: BINGO. Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can use property bindings concept something like

**TS Side**

```
htmlOfStuff = "<h1>HTML CODE</h1>";
```

**HTML side**

```
<div [innerHtml]="htmlOfStuff"></div>
```